# Replace Double slash to single slash c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2, vb.net-2010

I would like to ask how to replace double slash to single slash in C# Winforms. I am currently using vb.net 2010 ultimate and SQL Server 2008.

I was retrieving my Crystal Report path from my SQL Server, but it turns `\` into `\\\`.

I tried using

```
string.replace(@"\\\", @"\\")
```

but it still returns `\\\` in my path.

Please help

My code is

```
string path = Getvalue.Path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
myReportDocument.Load("@"+path);
```

Path stored in SQL Server

```
\\server\crystal\codes\Report\Summary_of_applicant.rpt
```

Returned data

```
\\careersql\\MIS\\codes\\Report\\Summary_of_applicant.rpt
```

Comment: Where are you seeing “\\careersql\\MIS\\codes\\Report\\Summary_of_applicant.rpt”? In the debugger? Do you see straight quotes `"` before and after the string? You are looking at a string literal, like what you would type in C#. The C# code `var s = "\\A\\B";` stores the string `\A\B` with no quotes and single backslashes. If you looked at this in the debugger it would show you `"\\A\\B"` just as in C#. In the debugger click on the little magnifying glass icon next to the string and select Text Visualizer; it will show you the actual contents not the literal.

Comment: Hey @DourHighArch i see it on the debugger. i ll try your suggestion thank you

Comment: @DourHighArch i tried what you suggested it seems that i was getting my value right. but why do i get error load report failed? if i directly code the same path it works but if i retrieve it from the database it doesn't?

Comment: Your path is probably an UNC and must start with \\. You encode that in C# with `@"\\"` or `"\\\\"`. You must *not* call `Replace(@"\\", @"\")` because that removes the double slashes, which are required. Do not follow the bad advice given in the answers to this question; that is what is causing your problems.; Please learn what the debugger is showing you. If you are getting the wrong data you must [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47465242/edit) your question to show us how you are getting your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon all thank you for all who comment and help.
the answer to my question is wrong encode path and code in the database.

wrong data = @"\careersql\MIS\codes\Report\Summary_of_applicant.rpt"

correct data = \sever\crystal\codes\Report\Summary_of_applicant.rpt

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to replace any string with another, but \ is a special char that must be escaped.

```
string path = Getvalue.Path.Replace("\\\\","\\");
```

I'd use the [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) to build the path though.

```
string reportFile = "Summary_of_applicant.rpt"; // or more complex path
string path = Path.Combine(GetValue.Path,reportFile);
```

Comment: Good morning @Obfuscate what is reportfile = Summary_of_applicant.rpt?

Comment: i tried your suggest but it still return "\\careersql\\MIS\\codes\\Report\\Summary_of_applicant.rpt"